# Deallocating the pointer but not its values

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

I have this type of code:

```cpp
class A
{
  private:
    int z;
    std::vector<B*> v;
  public:
    A();
    A(int z, std::vector<B*> v);
    ~A();
    // ...
    void setV(std::vector<B*> v);
}

class B
{
  // Some attributes
  B();
}

int main()
{
  A* a = new A();
  B* b = new B();
  b->setSomething(s);
  
  std::vector<B*> vec = {};
  vec.push_back(b);
  a->setV(vec);
  
  // ... 
  
  delete b;
  
  // ...
  
  delete a;
}
```

The problem is that I want to delete b before a. But I will delete the values pointed by b, that will be a problem for a.

If I just delete a, and not b, all the values are correctly deleted by this destructor:

```cpp
A::~A()
{
  for (B* b : this.v)
  {
    delete b;
  }
}
```

But valgrind says I have a 24B memory leak if I just delete a. Because I still have the b pointer not deallocated.

How can I delete b, before a, without losing the values pointed by b ?

Thank you

Comment: Use std::shared_ptr for something like this.

Comment: I think there's a lot of stuff wrong with this. 1) You are using a.setV as if a is statically allocated, but you used new, so it's not! 2) You can't simply 'delete pointers', only objects. The pointer is just an address. Deleting thus conceptually removes values from memory. 3) There is something called 'ownership'. In general the rule is that he who creates, should destroy. The destructor of A seems to think otherwise.

Comment: I recommend passing the vector as reference. But why do you use pointers here at all? Introducing an additional scope where `b` is declared should achieve a similar effect AND make sure the destructors are called, even if you exit the function using `return` before the `delete`s. `A a(); { B b(); b.setSomething(s); std::vector<B*> vec = {}; vec.push_back(&b); a.setV(vec); ... } ...`

Comment: [syntax errors corrected, I study your answers]

Comment: Don't use owning bare pointers.

Comment: One aspect of OOP is ownership. If you run in the problem you describe, you have a design flaw! You can hide the problem by using shared_ptr, but it is still a design problem